# subset rows nested in another variable

Tags: r, filter, dplyr

I have a dataset

```
dataframe <- data.frame(time = c(1,2.2,3,4.1,5.6,6.9,7,7.2,8.9,9.2,10,11,13,14,15),
               condition = c(1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3),
               trial = c("A","A","A","B","B","A","A","A","B","B","A","A","A","B","B"))
```

I want to subset the first two seconds in `time` per `trial` in each `condition`, such that my output will look like this:

```
 time condition trial
1     1         1     A
2     2         1     A
3     4         1     B
4     5         1     B
5     6         2     A
6     7         2     A
7     9         2     B
8    10         2     B
9    11         3     A
10   13         3     A
11   14         3     B
12   15         3     B
```

How can I do this using logical statements (e.g., <, >) in dplyr?

Comment: Can you specify your desired output? It's not clear to me as it is.

Comment: the desired output is specified above

Comment: Then it's not clear to me how you want to calculate your output `time` variable. Do you mean you want the first two entries for each condition/trial or really the first two seconds?

Comment: use `group_by` and `slice_head(n =2)`

Comment: I want the first two seconds or be able to specify any time period (e.g., time > 2 & time < 5). Was that clear? I'm happy to provide any additional details.

Comment: See if any of my answers provide the desired result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To return the first two entries you can do:

```
library(dplyr)

dataframe %>%
  group_by(condition, trial) %>%
  slice_head(n = 2)
```

Returns:

```
# A tibble: 12 x 3
# Groups:   condition, trial [6]
    time condition trial
   <dbl>     <dbl> <chr>
 1   1           1 A    
 2   2.2         1 A    
 3   4.1         1 B    
 4   5.6         1 B    
 5   6.9         2 A    
 6   7           2 A    
 7   8.9         2 B    
 8   9.2         2 B    
 9  10           3 A    
10  11           3 A    
11  14           3 B    
12  15           3 B
```

To return the first two seconds, you can do

```
dataframe %>%
  group_by(condition, trial) %>%
  filter(time <= min(time) + 2)
```

Returns:

```
# A tibble: 14 x 3
# Groups:   condition, trial [6]
    time condition trial
   <dbl>     <dbl> <chr>
 1   1           1 A    
 2   2.2         1 A    
 3   3           1 A    
 4   4.1         1 B    
 5   5.6         1 B    
 6   6.9         2 A    
 7   7           2 A    
 8   7.2         2 A    
 9   8.9         2 B    
10   9.2         2 B    
11  10           3 A    
12  11           3 A    
13  14           3 B    
14  15           3 B
```

Comment: the returning the first two second solution was exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!